# Independantly size controls in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I need to independantly size the controls on a fabric object.

Namely I have a rectangle and I want the top nad bottom drag handles for resizing to stretch to the widht of the object.

Currently the `cornerSize` property only allows you to scale the size, you can't change the shape or adjust them for each point independantly?

Or at least you can't from what I can tell.

Is there an easy way to achieve this in the library without having to re-implement all the functionality of the controls in new fabric objects?

Comment: I don't think fabricJs has such an option to change the color and size for each corner. You'll probably have to extend fabricJs to set fill, size and shape for each control (mt, mb, ml, mr, tr, tl, br, bl). An easy way I don't think it is. At least that I know.

Comment: Thanks... I ended up overrideing the fabric object prototype to do the work with some `cornerSizeOverrides`... If anyone else needs it I'll add some more polish and maybe I'll try and get it into the lib. I have a pull for discussion at https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/pull/2273